# GraphDB - Why don't all nodes with same schema appear on the visual graph

Tags: rdf, graphdb

I've inserted the following triples into my graphDB:

(Note I've replaced abc dot com with example dot com - as it wasn't letting me post)

```
<http://example.com/123> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://schema.org/Song> .
<http://example.com/456> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://schema.org/Song> .
<http://example.com/789> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://schema.org/Song> .
```

As shown here:

[image]

When I click on Visual Graph - I'd expect it show `Song` in the center then my 3 nodes coming off, however all I see is:

[image]

If I click on the schema, and try to view the graph from there - I again see no connected nodes.

[image]

[image]

Could someone explain where I am going wrong?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd say because the visualization is about instance data, not schema data. I mean, in the end there are just SPARQL queries that fetch the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more complex scenarious - check the [online documentation](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/devhub/custom-graph-views.html)
Otherwise, simpliest way to see your data, is to execute a `CONSTRUCT` query that renders the data of interest and then click on `Visual` button that is located on right, just above from the query results, e.g. execute:

`DESCRIBE <http://schema.org/Song>`

and then click on `Visual` button

HTH

Comment: Does it also visualize `rdf:type` triples via edges? I thought it maybe shows types in different colors or something like that?

Comment: No, `rdf:type` are not visualised. More over, these are used to select the colour of the node.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was thinking and this is also why the TO won't see any edges if you look at their sample data.

Answer (score 1):

The default Visual Graph configuration is optimized for datasets from linked data cloud like DBpedia, GeoNames, etc. By default OWL/RDFS schema predicates are not included, since they are going to clutter the visualization with often unwanted connections. In the default configuration there a predicate filter, which prevents you from seeing the OWL/RDFS schema in the interface:

```
FILTER(!strstarts(str(?p), "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#")
                && !strstarts(str(?p), "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#")
                && !strstarts(str(?p), "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#")
                && !strstarts(str(?p), "http://www.openrdf.org/schema/sesame#")
                && !strstarts(str(?p), "http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/dul/DUL.owl")
                && !strstarts(str(?p), "http://www.w3.org/ns/prov")
                && !strstarts(str(?p), "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPage")
                && !strstarts(str(?p), "http://dbpedia.org/property/wikiPage")
                && !strstarts(str(?p), "http://www.omg.org/spec/")
                && !strstarts(str(?p), "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/")
                && !strstarts(str(?p), "http://factforge.net/")
                # The rest of the predicates point to IRIs but are actually URLs that should not be interpreted
                # as IRIs but literals. They should be listed in resourceProperties.sparql too
                && ?p NOT IN (<http://dbpedia.org/property/logo>,
                    <http://dbpedia.org/property/hasPhotoCollection>,
                    <http://dbpedia.org/property/website>,
                    <http://dbpedia.org/property/homepage>,
                    <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/thumbnail>,
                    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/depiction>,
                    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/homepage>,
                    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/mbox>)
            )
}
```

What you can do is to create a custom Visual Graph. Create your own visual graph configuration and on the Graph Expansion query choose the "Unfiltered object properties" which will load all predicates, including the rdf and rdfs ones.

1. Go to Visual Graph.
2. In Advanced graph configuration create a new Graph Expansion config.
3. Select from the sample queries in the config "Unfiltered Object properties".
4. You can use the newly created graph by clicking on it and search for the resource.